# SupersetApiError: Forbidden when I want to embed Apache Superset im React app

Tags: apache-superset

I want to embed Apache Superset to my React app.

In superset_config.py I added: FEATURE_FLAGS = {..., "EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True}.

Embed dashboard->Settings->Allowed Domains: specified "http://localhost:3000"

Added "myUser" with roles: Public, Gamma.

And in superset_config.py added:

```
TALISMAN_ENABLED = False
ENABLE_CORS = True
HTTP_HEADERS={"X-Frame-Options":"ALLOWALL"}
```

App.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { embedDashboard } from "@superset-ui/embedded-sdk"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  const getToken = async () => {
            return "token_value"  //get Insomnia
        }
  useEffect(() => {
    const embed = async () => {
      await embedDashboard({
        id: "dashboard_id", // given by the Superset embedding UI
        supersetDomain: "http://localhost:8088",
        mountPoint: document.getElementById("dashboard"), // html element in which iframe render
        fetchGuestToken: () => getToken(),
        dashboardUiConfig: {
          hideTitle: true,
          hideChartControls: true,
          hideTab: true,
        },
      })
    }
    if (document.getElementById("dashboard")) {
      embed()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>How to Embed Superset Dashboard into React</h1>
      <div id="dashboard" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

When npm start error:

```
SupersetApiError: Forbidden
i types.ts:120
    n handleError.ts:91
```

How fix bug and embedded Apache superset?